# Jenkins cant find Pull request ref specs from TFS Git Repository to build pr-merges

Tags: git, jenkins, tfs

I am trying to automate Jenkins (atm. 2.60.3, Team Foundation Server Plug-in
5.121.0, git plugin 3.5.1, git client plugin 2.5.0) together with a TFS (15.117.26714.0)

"Enable Push trigger for all jobs / team status for all jobs" is present in the Jenkins configuration, the soap api connection does work when using the Test connection button.

I have a Multibranch pipeline project configured with a git repository on that TFS server; my main problem is, that pull requests are not found when scanning the refspecs; the refspecs in my Multibranch pipeline Project are:

Ref Spec

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/@{remote}/*
```

and Ref Spec

```
+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/@{remote}/pull/*
```

we updated from TFS 2015 where, if i recall correctly, the refspecs were

```
+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/@{remote}/pr/*
```

and with the old 2015 TFS it was possible to find the pr/ refs and get the multibranch job like

```
<JENKINSHOST>:8080/job/MultibranchJob/job/pr%252f<PRID>
```

- although this was a few months back, and I also have updated the LTS version of Jenkins and all the plugins.

This in turn would be started to verify if the pull request which should be completed does not break the build. (As far as I know identifying pull requests is not yet implemented in the TFS plugin as in the bitbucket and github plugins)

neither @{remote}/pr/* nor @{remote}/pull/* seem to find the refspecs.
The Jenkins Host has an own compiled git version 2.13.3, because the Centos 7 git was too old to communicate properly with TFS 2017.

But the pull request ref specs are nowhere to be found:

```
Started by user Jenkins admin
[Tue Aug 29 12:49:03 CEST 2017] Starting branch indexing...
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to MYOWNTFSGITREPO
 > git config remote.origin.url MYOWNTFSGITREPO # timeout=10
Fetching origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull/* +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* 
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote --symref MYOWNTFSGITREPO # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote MYOWNTFSGITREPO # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to MYOWNTFSGITREPO
 > git config remote.origin.url MYOWNTFSGITREPO # timeout=10
Fetching & pruning origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/pull/* +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*  --prune
Listing remote references...
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote -h MYOWNTFSGITREPO # timeout=10
Checking branches...
  Checking branch develop
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
Changes detected: develop (51e43e3456f49506086ad5649282695d9f0eff7d → 6008de4da7d017b35cb73cf28963057b8512584c)
Did not schedule build for branch: develop
  Checking branch master
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
Changes detected: master (5c2f4df13a6cf53700ff1562d5347c31ff2a8d69 → b856b96743870bc80d9523c79922b01bfe0f363b)
Did not schedule build for branch: master
  Checking branch feature/myFeature
      ‘Jenkinsfile’ found
    Met criteria
No changes detected: feature/myFeature (still at 72fa143c6cbf4cf492129ad43f9a0053d5edf785)
Processed 3 branches
[Tue Aug 29 12:49:03 CEST 2017] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 0.57 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

although if i use git ls-remote from my dev-pc:

```
$ git ls-remote
From MYOWNTFSGITREPO
b856b96743870bc80d9523c79922b01bfe0f363b        HEAD
6008de4da7d017b35cb73cf28963057b8512584c        refs/heads/develop
72fa143c6cbf4cf492129ad43f9a0053d5edf785        refs/heads/feature/myFeature
b856b96743870bc80d9523c79922b01bfe0f363b        refs/heads/master
d6998b37fb29dc5eb6eaac812b8af58e8f31d402        refs/pull/26/merge
```

is it possible that the --prune removes the merge because it could probably not be reachable? But that merge should have parents in both branches that are used for the pull request, right?

Am I missing something painfully obvious?

The scanning of the repo works, else all the other branches could not been found.

I know making own branch for the pull request is somewhat hacky, although it did work to verify that the merged code works. If there is a better way to implement the testing with a multibranch project I am absolutely open for a different approach.

edit:

trying on my dev-pc all the commands from the log above; the last

```
git ls-remote -h MYOWNTFSREPO
```

limits to only heads, is there any possibility to circumvent that?
git ls-remote MYOWNTFSREPO would also give me /refs/pull//merge, which would be exactly what I want to start the building of the Pr merge commits.

Comment: To narrow down the issue is  related  to the remote git repository hold on TFS2017 server or not. Suggest you also give a  try with other remote repos  hold on  GitHub or bitbuck.

Comment: Sorry I hoped my edit did clarify that better: due to the fact the last git ls-remote is used with -h, it only gets /refs/heads and not anything like /refs/tags (which i wouldn't want here now anyways) nor /refs/pull, where my /refs/pull/<PRID>/merge refs would reside;

 This leads me to believe it probably has more to do in regards of the git plugin or the multibranch pipeline plugin; still, if there would be a better way to verify an ok build for a pull request with TFS2017 before I have to merge I am happy for any ideas. Edited question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Pull request in Multibranch Pieline project is only supported with "GitHub" and "Bitbucket" branch sources for now. It cannot be achieved with Git plugin since the plugin can only discover branches while the Github Source Branch Plugin support "Discover pull request from origin".

> **Supporting Pull Requests**
>
> With the "GitHub" or "Bitbucket" Branch Sources, Multibranch Pipelines can be used for validating pull/change
> requests. This functionality is provided, respectively, by the GitHub
> Branch Source and Bitbucket Branch Source plugins. Please consult
> their documentation for further information on how to use those
> plugins.

Refer to this link for details: [Branches and Pull Requests](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#supporting-pull-requests).